# Foreach loop only looping once

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to loop through all names in `$names` and convert them using regex. The conversion is fine, but I cannot find a way to loop through every name.

At the moment, only one value is returned: "Name: COOPE, Sebastian"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>PHP Arrays</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>PHP Arrays</h1>
<?php
        $names = array("Sebastian Coope", "Andrew Craig", "Prof Karl Tuyls", "Dr Ullrich Hustadt", "Dr Michele Zito");

            foreach($names as $name){

            function rewriteText($match){
                $firstName = $match[2];
                $surname = $match[3];
                return strtoupper($surname).', '.$firstName;
            }

            $altered =  preg_replace_callback(
                "/(Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Prof)?\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)/",
                "rewriteText",
                $name);

            echo "Name: $altered<br>\n";
            }
?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` will show _Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rewriteText() (previously declared_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rewriteText() (previously declared in /path/to/file.php:13) in /path/to/file.php on line 13

Just define your function outside the `foreach` loop

```
$names = array("Sebastian Coope", "Andrew Craig", "Prof Karl Tuyls", "Dr Ullrich Hustadt", "Dr Michele Zito");

function rewriteText($match){
    $firstName = $match[2];
    $surname = $match[3];
    return strtoupper($surname).', '.$firstName;
}

foreach($names as $name) {
    $altered =  preg_replace_callback(
        "/(Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Prof)?\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)/",
        "rewriteText",
        $name);

    echo "Name: $altered<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Or wrap it inside `if(!function_exists('rewriteText')) { function rewriteText(...){...} }`

Comment: Also no need to do the loop, it will work on arrays: https://3v4l.org/Ftujt

Answer (score 0):

Another option, similar to @Felippe Duarte

```
$rewriteText = function ($match){
    $firstName = $match[2];
    $surname = $match[3];
    return strtoupper($surname).', '.$firstName;
};

foreach($names as $name){
    $altered =  preg_replace_callback(
       "/(Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Prof)?\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)/",
        $rewriteText,
     $name);

     echo "Name: $altered<br>\n";
}
```

Typically you would put the anonymous function right in `preg_replace_callback` but when it's in a loop I like doing it outside.

Another advantage of Closures is that they can overwrite themself's so you don't have to check if a function exists, but I try not to overwrite them in loops for performance reasons.

Again thanks to @Felippe Duarte

I just wanted to show another way to do it.

Cheers!